# Detect mouse pointer disappearance

Tags: java, android, mouse-cursor

When connecting a mouse to an Android device, there is a pointer. If you do not move the mouse for about 15 seconds, it vanishes. This is how Android works.

Is there any way to catch the event of the mouse pointer disappearing?
Update:
I need to support API level 19 and on, so things like `onPointerCaptureChanged`, even if they are a solution, are not relevant (it was added on API level 26)

Comment: mouse pointer ?

Comment: @YamenNassif What are you asking exactly?

Comment: what do you mean by mouser pointer on android, this is what i am asking xD

Comment: as far as i am concerned Android system is made for mobiles where usually people dont just plug there mouses!

Comment: @YamenNassif in that case, this question is not for you man... If you do wish to expand your knowledge a bit, google it and see this is a valid use case. It is pretty similar to other input devices, such as remote controller for Android TV.

Comment: i know, i used to have mouse connected to my phones long time before android, as far as i remember it was Nokia C7 when i first did this with the usb thing! but i sill don't think its a relevant question to Android programming rather than Android OS, anyhow let me see what i can find for that

Comment: I believe this is what you are looking for : https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/movement.html

Comment: Thanks for trying, but no. I'm familiar with that, it talks about the tracking - I asked if I can detect the act of pointer becoming inactive. Of course I can keep track of tracking and detect it myself using another thread, but I asked if there's a simple way

Comment: it was quite weird for me to see someone asking about this! and sometimes people just ask random questions about some random stuff without even reading thats why i posted the link, anyhow i believe the answer i added is what you need

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169739/discussion-between-yamen-nassif-and-yakobom).

Answer (score 0):

it will be something like that:

```
public void onFocusChange(){
    if(!hasPointerCapture()){
         // do your magic
    }
}
```

since onFocusChange is event (you need to capture it) and it works on InputEvents and mouse is to be considered an Input device This should work

[`hasPointerCapture`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#hasPointerCapture()) is exactly what are you looking for i will tell if the mouse is disappeared or not

Comment: It doesn't work. Anyway, focus change is relevant when the user does something, the pointer disappearing due to inactivity does not change the focus. If any, onPointerCaptureChanged might help - but it is supported from API level 26, and I have to support older API

Comment: @yakobom , you should specify the API level in the question along with your research about onPointerCaptureChanged etc.

Comment: @rjdkolb thanks, I added it and rephrased a bit since it was claimed to be an unclear question.